# C program that uses functions to verify security codes

Tags: c, function, file

I'm trying to write a program that uses the Luhn algorithm to verify security codes. The program needs to:

read security codes from a file and enter them into an array

use one function to read the security codes

use another function to verify them

to verify them, the digits in the odd position will be summed together. The digits in the even positions will be multiplied by two; once they're multiplied by two, if the number is less than ten, it is added to a sum of the evens; if it's more than ten, the sum of the digits of the number are added to the sum of the evens. So, if the number in the second position in the array is 8, it's multiplied by 2 to get 16, then 1 + 6 = 7 is added to the sum of the evens. There's more to verifying the codes, but this is the part I'm working on right now.

The problems I have: I don't think my function for scanning the codes from the file is correct. Each of the codes in the file has 20 digits so when I was declaring the array variable I did: int sc[20]. However, there's more than one 20 digit security code, and I'm not sure how to fix that.

And second: I'm not sure how to approach the second part of summing the evens (the part where if the number multiplied by two is greater than ten, it's digits are added to the sum of the evens).

This is the first few lines from the file (the entire file is very long so I'm just listing the first few lines):

```
0 7 6 1 1 6 6 2 6 8 5 1 5 5 7 7 7 8 0 2 

2 5 1 6 2 1 8 2 4 3 0 9 1 9 1 1 3 1 3 8
 
1 3 3 4 5 4 5 2 8 6 1 8 9 3 7 6 2 2 0 5
```

And this is my code so far:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

ReadSecurityCode(FILE* codes, int sc[]);

int main(void) {
    int sc[20], i;
    FILE* codes;

    codes = fopen("SecurityCodes.txt", "r");

    while (fscanf(codes, "%c\n", &sc) != EOF) {
        ReadSecurityCode(codes, sc[20]);
    }

    fclose(codes);
    return(0);
}


int ReadSecurityCode(FILE* codes, int sc[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        fscanf(codes, "%d", &sc[i]);
    }
    return(sc[20]);
}


int isCodeValid(int sc[]) {
    int i, sumodds = 0, sumevens = 0, sumtotal;
    for (i = 1; i < 20; i = i + 2) {
        sumodds = sumodds + sc[i];
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i = i + 2) {
        sc[i] = sc[i] * 2;
        if (sc[i] < 10) {
            sumevens = sumevens + sc[i];
        }
        else {

        }
    }
    return(sumtotal);
}
```

Comment: Your question includes snippets of code, it's much more helpful to share a [mre]. Here is an implementation of the algorithm in various languages https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/luhn-algorithm/

Comment: 1) your prototype should include "int": `int ReadSecurityCode(FILE* codes, int sc[]);`, 2) Your should check the return value from each [fscanf()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3p.html) in case of read error, 3) You're overwriting array sc each time you loop, 4) You're never calling IsCodeValid() at all

Comment: 1-digit number is less than 4 bits of information (log2(10 == 3.3) . Consider using char (sizeof(char) == 1) instead of int (sizeof(int) might be 8 on your platform) for each digit.

Comment: Also turn up warning levels on your compiler.  It will tell you that the variable `i` is not used in `main()`.  `fopen()` can fail so check the return code.

Comment: After turnin up your warning level you might also get some warning that `&sc` does not have proper type for format specifier `%c`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to read and validate each line as you go.  In the code you posted, this means calling `isCodeValid()` in while loop where you read the records:

```
    while (fscanf(codes, "%c\n", &sc) != EOF) {
        ReadSecurityCode(codes, sc);
        isCodeValid(sc);
    }
```

Consider using a char instead of int to store each digit (i.e. `char sc[20]`).

Not sure why ReadSecurityCode returns the first element, but `scanf()` can fail, so you might want to return an error code instead and check it.  Also, I suggest that you use `ReadSecurityCode()` to read a line including the newline.

You probably also want to do something based the return value of `isCodeValid()`.  The is-naming suggest you are returning a boolean but you are returning a sum.

With the above suggestions it would be:

```
   while (!ReadSecurityCode(codes, sc)) {
      if (!isCodeValid(sc)) {
           printf("%s is invalid\n", sc);
      }
   }
```